# Typeclasses in Common Lisp

Tags: haskell, common-lisp, typeclass

I'm wondering if there's a way to emulate Haskell's `typeclasses` in Common Lisp.

Generic functions allow `overloading`, and it's possible to define types using `deftype`(which could be defined by membership to some list of instances, for example).

But I can't `dispatch` on a type. Is there a way to make a class a subclass(and a subtype) of some other class after its definition(e.g. making the `cons` class a subclass of a `sequence` class, without redefining `cons`)?

Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow best for real actual programming problems, not so good for speculation if programming language A could support features of programming language B...

Comment: I did hesitate to post here, thought it was really a question of not just whether, but also how such a feature could be implemented(which is a programming concern, no?). Anyway, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: I want to know whether Lisp can do it. Even if whether Lisp can be like Haskell is not relevant, whether Lisp can do typeclasses is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2):

Type classes in Haskell are a means to statically look up implementations for "interfaces" in the form of dictionaries (similarly to how vtables in e.g. C++ are used but (almost) fully statically, unlike C++ which does dynamic dispatch at runtime). Common Lisp however is a dynamically typed language so such lookup would make no sense. However you can implement your own look up of "type class" implementations (instances) at runtime — a design not too hard to imagine in a language as expressive as Common Lisp.

P.S. Python's Zope has an adaption mechanism with very similar charactetistics, if you feel like referring to an existing solution in a dynamic setting.

Comment: Haskell's instance dictionaries are not particularly more static than C++'s vtables. They specialize at compile time when possible, but otherwise they are indeed passed at runtime.

Comment: passed at runtime but there is no dynamic lookup because there's no dynamic dispatch because there is no subtype polymorphism aka (type) inheritance — have I missed something?

Comment: I'm not sure. It seems the terminology is a bit fuzzy. In the presence of polymorphic recursion (even in Haskell 98) or GADTs (in real Haskell), a specific type may not be knowable, and a specific instance may not quite exist, until runtime. Isn't that the essence of dynamic dispatch?

Comment: I'm possibly not experienced enough: can you provide an example? I'd like to learn. Also, if what you say is true, doesn't that mean Haskell has RTTI and not complete runtime type erasure?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot modify the class hierarchy in the way you envision, but you can achieve pretty much the same effect.

Suppose that your definition of a `sequence` is that it has a method for the function `sequence-length`.

```
(defclass sequence ...)
(defmethod sequence-length ((s sequence)) ...)
```

Then you can easily extend your `sequence-length` method to conses:

```
(defmethod sequence-length ((s cons))
    (length s))
```

Did that create a new class that includes `cons`?  Not really.  You can express the type of things that have a `sequence-length` method by saying `(or sequence cons)`, but that's not really useful.